# How to handle hidden field / dropdown selectors when submitting a form?

Tags: r, screen-scraping, rvest

I want to submit the following nucleotide sequence in FASTA format to https://www.imgt.org/IMGT_vquest/input. I followed online tutorials/examples to set the fields of the form and when I check the filled form, everything looks ok:ish. But after submitting, the sessions URL is still the "input" website, so it seems that something goes wrong. When navigating to the website and not filling in species (human in this example), or the locus (IGH in the example), or the sequence is in the wrong format, then the submission will not go through. So I suspect, that something is wrong with my submission through R. But I am at a loss how to check this - I don't know how to save the session as an HTML file so I can open it with a browser; or how to troubleshoot this otherwise.

I have some suspects:

#### Suspect 1 - the sequence:

This is the way a sequence in FASTA format should be formatted (a header preceded by `>`, a line break, then the sequence without line breaks). Not sure if submitting a string with `\n` as line break works in html forms, or if another line break symbol is needed.

```
>test
GGTTCTCCTTGTTGCCATTTTAAAAGGTAATTCATGGAGAACTAGAGATAGTGTGAGTGGACGTGAGTGAGAGAAACAGTGGATATGTGTGGCAGTTTCTGACCTTGGTGTCTCTTTGTTTGCAGATGTCCAGTGTGAGGTGCAGCTGGTGGAGTCTGGGGGAGGCTTGGTCCAGCCTGGGGGGTCCCTGAGACTCTCCTGTTCAGCCTCTGGATTCACCTTCAGTAGCTATGCTATGCACTGGGTCCGCCAGGCTCCAGGGAAGGGACTGGAATATGTTTCAGCTATTAGTAGTAATGGGGGTAGCACATACTACGCAGACTCCGTGAAGGGCAGATTCACCATCTCCAGAGACAATTCCAAGAACACGCTGTATCTTCAAATGAGCAGTCTGAGAGCTGAGGACACGGCTGTGTATTACTGTGTGAAAGATCCGGAGGAGTTCGGTGGCTGGTACTGGGGGTTGGGCTACTGGGGCCAGGGAACCCT
```

#### Suspect 2 - hidden field:

When I submit the species, "human" I get this warning:

> Warning message:
> Setting value of hidden field 'species'.

-> I suspect that I have to set the values differently if these parameters are selected from drop down menus on  the website? How is that done? I didn't find good examples for this...

Here is the code I used.

```
#load libraries libraries
if (!require("tidyverse")){
  install.packages("tidyverse")
  library("tidyverse")
}

if (!require("rvest")){
  install.packages("rvest")
  library("rvest")
}

#set the url and the sequence to submit
url <- ("https://www.imgt.org/IMGT_vquest/input")

sequenceFASTA <- ">test\nGGTTCTCCTTGTTGCCATTTTAAAAGGTAATTCATGGAGAACTAGAGATAGTGTGAGTGGACGTGAGTGAGAGAAACAGTGGATATGTGTGGCAGTTTCTGACCTTGGTGTCTCTTTGTTTGCAGATGTCCAGTGTGAGGTGCAGCTGGTGGAGTCTGGGGGAGGCTTGGTCCAGCCTGGGGGGTCCCTGAGACTCTCCTGTTCAGCCTCTGGATTCACCTTCAGTAGCTATGCTATGCACTGGGTCCGCCAGGCTCCAGGGAAGGGACTGGAATATGTTTCAGCTATTAGTAGTAATGGGGGTAGCACATACTACGCAGACTCCGTGAAGGGCAGATTCACCATCTCCAGAGACAATTCCAAGAACACGCTGTATCTTCAAATGAGCAGTCTGAGAGCTGAGGACACGGCTGTGTATTACTGTGTGAAAGATCCGGAGGAGTTCGGTGGCTGGTACTGGGGGTTGGGCTACTGGGGCCAGGGAACCCT\n"

cat(sequenceFASTA)

#setwd("/Users/chmet515/Downloads/IMGT_quest playground")

#start a session
sess <- session(url)

#get the form
form_unfilled <- sess %>% html_node("form") %>% html_form()

#pass the required parameters to the form
form_filled   <- form_unfilled %>% html_form_set("species"="human", "sequences" = sequenceFASTA, "strains" = "IGH")



#submit the form and read the returned webpage
sess_results <- session_submit(sess,form_filled)
sess_results$handle$url
sess_results$response$request$fields

results_html <- sess_results %>% read_html()
results_html[2]
```

I tried to submit the fasta sequence string with the HTML code for a line break `<br>`, but this didn't help.

I used dev tools and website inspection in the safari browser to check that "human" and "IGH" are the right strings to set for "species" and "strains" respectively:

```
speciesData = [{"id":"human","label":"Homo sapiens (human)","loci":[{"id":"IG","label":"IG"},{"id":"IGH","label":"IGH"},{"id":"IGK","label":"IGK"},{"id":"IGL","label":"IGL"},{"id":"TR","label":"TR"},{"id":"TRA","label":"TRA"},{"id":"TRB","label":"TRB"},{"id":"TRG","label":"TRG"},{"id":"TRD","label":"TRD"}],"strainPrefix":"Homo sapiens","strains":[]}
```

Comment: There are more fields you probably have to fiddle with, maybe add and/or delete a few in addition to setting existing ones,  there's some javascript-driven logic involved so it might be no so straightforward to get it right with static scrapers / http clients like rvest, though not saying it can't be done. Perhaps check the requests-based Python implementation - https://github.com/ShawHahnLab/vquest - and use it through `reticulate` in R? Or use RSelinum or Chromte to work with a browser-rendered site with full js support.

Comment: Thanks @margusl. I am new to the whole web-scraping business. I have actually one script with the python IMGT/vQuest library running (on my private computer), but it's not reporting all the readouts I need. Additionally, the IT restrictions at my workspace make it difficult to install python, let alone git etc, so I am trying to work my way towards a solution in R, which I can then customise to our needs and be independent of others maintaining and updating libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to be filed under *"if it's stupid but it works, then .. "* or *"abusing rvest 101"*.

As we are dealing with a javascript-driven site, filling forms can get a bit tricky, especially when those forms are submitted with 89 set fields (+/-, depending on selections). What usually works is copying the submitted request from browser's dev tools as CURL and converting it to `httr` with https://curlconverter.com/r/ or passing it through `httr2::curl_translate()`, but in this case, it would need some more debugging and fiddling. Somewhat of a "solution", at least for an early prototype, is using parsed form data from *Network > Request > Payload* view of dev.tools:
[image: form data]

We could bluntly copy it, parse it as delimited text and build our own form fields list for `rvest`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(readr)
library(purrr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

url <- ("https://www.imgt.org/IMGT_vquest/input")
sequenceFASTA <- ">test\nGGTTCTCCTTGTTGCCATTTTAAAAGGTAATTCATGGAGAACTAGAGATAGTGTGAGTGGACGTGAGTGAGAGAAACAGTGGATATGTGTGGCAGTTTCTGACCTTGGTGTCTCTTTGTTTGCAGATGTCCAGTGTGAGGTGCAGCTGGTGGAGTCTGGGGGAGGCTTGGTCCAGCCTGGGGGGTCCCTGAGACTCTCCTGTTCAGCCTCTGGATTCACCTTCAGTAGCTATGCTATGCACTGGGTCCGCCAGGCTCCAGGGAAGGGACTGGAATATGTTTCAGCTATTAGTAGTAATGGGGGTAGCACATACTACGCAGACTCCGTGAAGGGCAGATTCACCATCTCCAGAGACAATTCCAAGAACACGCTGTATCTTCAAATGAGCAGTCTGAGAGCTGAGGACACGGCTGTGTATTACTGTGTGAAAGATCCGGAGGAGTTCGGTGGCTGGTACTGGGGGTTGGGCTACTGGGGCCAGGGAACCCT\n"

sess <- session(url)

form_template <- sess %>% 
  html_element("form") %>% 
  html_form()


# form field generator, will be used with purrr::imap,
# which passes arguments as (value, name) to its function
fake_field_generator <- function(value, name) {
  attr <- list(name = name, value = value, type = "text")
  rvest:::rvest_field(
    type = attr$type,
    name = attr$name,
    value = attr$value,
    attr = attr
  )
}

# overwrite form_template fields and values with a list generated from
# previously captured payload, we want a named list that can be assgined to
# form_template$fields
form_template$fields <- chrome_form_data %>% 
  read_delim(delim = ":", col_names = c("name", "value")) %>% 
  mutate(value = trimws(value), .keep = "unused") %>% 
  deframe() %>% 
  as.list() %>% 
  assign_in("sequences", sequenceFASTA) %>% 
  imap(fake_field_generator)

# while the field list is overwritten, form attributes (name / method, action with jsessionid) remain:
form_template
#> <form> 'main_form' (POST https://www.imgt.org/IMGT_vquest/analysis;jsessionid=0B66F788E24C867BDD750...)
#>   <field> (text) species: human
#>   <field> (text) receptorOrLocusType: IGH
#>   <field> (text) inputType: inline
#>   <field> (text) sequences: >test\nGGTTCTCCTT...
#>   <field> (text) resultType: detailed
#>   <field> (text) outputType: HTML
#      ...

# for verbose mode:  session_submit(sess,form_unfilled, ,httr::verbose())
sess_results <- session_submit(sess, form_template)

# Extract summary table from response:
sess_results %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_element("table.result_summary") %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  janitor::clean_names() %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), str_squish)) 
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   result_summary_test              productive_igh_rearr…¹ productive_igh_rearr…²
#>   <chr>                            <chr>                  <chr>                 
#> 1 V-GENE and allele                Homsap IGHV3-64D*06 F  score = 1440          
#> 2 J-GENE and allele                Homsap IGHJ5*01 F, or… score = 98            
#> 3 D-GENE and allele by IMGT/Junct… Homsap IGHD6-19*01 F   D-REGION is in readin…
#> 4 FR-IMGT lengths, CDR-IMGT lengt… [25.17.38.5]           [8.8.16]              
#> 5 JUNCTION length (in nt) and dec… 54 nt = (11)+2{12}-10… (3'V)3'{N1}5'(D)3'{N2…
#> # ℹ abbreviated names:
#> #   ¹​productive_igh_rearranged_sequence_no_stop_codon_and_in_frame_junction,
#> #   ²​productive_igh_rearranged_sequence_no_stop_codon_and_in_frame_junction_2
#> # ℹ 1 more variable:
#> #   productive_igh_rearranged_sequence_no_stop_codon_and_in_frame_junction_3 <chr>
```

Submitted form data copied from Chrome:

```r
# sequences will be set later,
# __multiselect_strains, fileSequences seem to have no use in this case -- removed
chrome_form_data <- "species: human
receptorOrLocusType: IGH
inputType: inline
sequences: 
resultType: detailed
outputType: html
nbNtPerLine: 60
dv_nbNtPerLine: 60
dv_nbAlignedSequence: 5
dv_V_GENEalignment: true
__checkbox_dv_V_GENEalignment: true
__checkbox_dv_D_GENEalignment: true
dv_J_GENEalignment: true
__checkbox_dv_J_GENEalignment: true
dv_IMGTjctaResults: true
__checkbox_dv_IMGTjctaResults: true
dv_eligibleD_GENE: false
dv_JUNCTIONseq: true
__checkbox_dv_JUNCTIONseq: true
dv_V_REGIONalignment: true
__checkbox_dv_V_REGIONalignment: true
dv_V_REGIONtranlation: true
__checkbox_dv_V_REGIONtranlation: true
dv_V_REGIONprotdisplay: true
__checkbox_dv_V_REGIONprotdisplay: true
dv_V_REGIONmuttable: true
__checkbox_dv_V_REGIONmuttable: true
dv_V_REGIONmutstats: true
__checkbox_dv_V_REGIONmutstats: true
dv_V_REGIONhotspots: true
__checkbox_dv_V_REGIONhotspots: true
dv_IMGTgappedVDJseq: true
__checkbox_dv_IMGTgappedVDJseq: true
dv_IMGTAutomat: true
__checkbox_dv_IMGTAutomat: true
dv_IMGTCollierdePerles: true
__checkbox_dv_IMGTCollierdePerles: true
dv_IMGTCollierdePerlesType: 0
sv_V_GENEalignment: true
__checkbox_sv_V_GENEalignment: true
sv_V_REGIONalignment: true
__checkbox_sv_V_REGIONalignment: true
sv_V_REGIONtranslation: true
__checkbox_sv_V_REGIONtranslation: true
sv_V_REGIONprotdisplay: true
__checkbox_sv_V_REGIONprotdisplay: true
sv_V_REGIONprotdisplay2: true
__checkbox_sv_V_REGIONprotdisplay2: true
sv_V_REGIONprotdisplay3: true
__checkbox_sv_V_REGIONprotdisplay3: true
sv_V_REGIONfrequentAA: true
__checkbox_sv_V_REGIONfrequentAA: true
sv_IMGTjctaResults: true
__checkbox_sv_IMGTjctaResults: true
xv_summary: true
__checkbox_xv_summary: true
xv_IMGTgappedNt: true
__checkbox_xv_IMGTgappedNt: true
xv_ntseq: true
__checkbox_xv_ntseq: true
xv_IMGTgappedAA: true
__checkbox_xv_IMGTgappedAA: true
xv_AAseq: true
__checkbox_xv_AAseq: true
xv_JUNCTION: true
__checkbox_xv_JUNCTION: true
xv_V_REGIONmuttable: true
__checkbox_xv_V_REGIONmuttable: true
xv_V_REGIONmutstatsNt: true
__checkbox_xv_V_REGIONmutstatsNt: true
xv_V_REGIONmutstatsAA: true
__checkbox_xv_V_REGIONmutstatsAA: true
xv_V_REGIONhotspots: true
__checkbox_xv_V_REGIONhotspots: true
xv_parameters: true
__checkbox_xv_parameters: true
__checkbox_xv_scFv: true
IMGTrefdirSet: 1
IMGTrefdirAlleles: true
V_REGIONsearchIndel: false
nbD_GENE: -1
nbVmut: -1
nbDmut: -1
nbJmut: -1
nb5V_REGIONignoredNt: 0
nb3V_REGIONaddedNt: 0
scfv: false
cllSubsetSearch: false"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for posting a solution! I am chewing on generating "chrome_form_data" - will need to install the appropriate web dev tools, as Safari web inspector seems to lack the required functionality...or isn't very obvious about it ;-)